# "Cross-thread operation not valid" if ComboBox.DropDownStyle == Simple

Tags: c#, .net, windows, combobox, thread-safety

I have a Forms that is shown in a method called through Invoke because that method is called from a different thread. In the form I need to open I have a UserControl with a ComboBox in it. If the `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` is `Simple` the form.Show explodes throwing

> InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'comboBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

If I set ComoBox.DropDownStyle in the default value (DropDown) I have no problem.

I now this is kind of hard to understand (even believe) so here there is a simplified example to reproduce it:

1. Create a new winforms project.
2. Create two forms and a user control.
3. In the user control create a ComboBox.
4. In the Form2 put an instance of the user control.
5. In the Form1 code put this:

```
private Form form;
private delegate void ShowDelegate();
private ShowDelegate showDelegate;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showDelegate = Show;
    new Thread(Run).Start();
}

private void Run()
{
    form = new Form2();
    Invoke(showDelegate);
}

private void Show()
{
    form.Show();
}
```

Remember to set the event to `Form1_Load`.

1. Run it and see it working.
2. Change the `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` to `Simple` and see it not working!

Any help with this issue please?

Comment: Your instructions are incomplete, where do we place the UserControl ?

Comment: You're right. Sorry. In the form2, I'll edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Quick thought - move the `form = new Form2()` from Run to the `Form1_Load` event. My guess is the form may need to be created on the UI thread.

Comment: Lesson learned: not all cross-thread calls are necessarily invalid, so you may think you're invoking properly until you actually make a call that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simply moving

```
form = new Form2();
```

To your Show() method, it will work then.

The Form gets initialized on the thread you start, it works then. But you might want to check the behavior in the long term ...

Comment: You might also want to rename your Show() method since it does hide Form's base method ...

Comment: Yes.. I didn't thought too much the method name because it was just to illustrate my situation. With this you are saying, I realized: I'm trying to show the form (and getting the error) in the GUI thread, but I'm creating the form (and its controls) in the other thread. Thanks!